# Multiple times Point in time recovery in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Can we perform point in time recovery more than one time using same recovery.conf file, because the recovery.conf file changes to recovery.done after a one restoration of `wal` file.

What if I want to do another `wal` file restoration at a different time using same recovery.conf file.I can't do that? Or do I have to again do a `pg_basebackup` and then create a new recovery file each time in my data directory of Postgres to retore next `wal` file

Answer (score 1):

Once recovery is done, you cannot go back.

You have to restore the backup again and start from scratch.

The only alternative is using `pg_rewind`, but that can only reset a cluster to the state of another cluster (and you probably don't have that other cluster).